# Criar App manipulando site externo

Tags: java, jquery, android, html5, ajax

Eu quero criar um app para um site que não tem versão mobile, então preciso mostrar para o usuário apenas 04 campos na tela (login, senha, cadastre-se e ok).
Como posso fazer isso

O site não é meu e não tenho acesso ao código fonte.

A primeira imagem é o site original e a segunda é como Eu quero que ele apareça no App Android?

Como faço isso em Java ou em HTML (html, javascript, jquery, ajax)?

Eu ja utilizei o WebView, mas não consegui fazer estas alterações no layout, o máximo que consegui foi colocar um Zoom, ficou horrível, pois o usuário precisa ficar se movendo pela tela, para inputar os dados de login e senha.

Por onde Eu começo? Quais técnicas utilizar para fazer isso que Eu preciso.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer criar um site ou um app tipo apk?
Caso for um site pesquise sobre responsividade, utilize medidas em porcentagem (%) no css ao invés de pixels (px). Link: http://tableless.com.br/introducao-ao-responsive-web-design/. Caso queira um criar um apk, para android por exemplo, tente usar o PhoneGap. Link: http://phonegap.com/

Comment: Eu qero criar um apk mesmo, mas minha dúvida é se com o Phonegap Eu conseguirei manipular o layout deste site, para Ele ficar mais amigável ao usuário final.

Comment: Pode manipular o layout com html, css e javascript

Answer (score 0):

O melhor jeito de você seguir com isso é usar alguma biblioteca que simule clicks em componentes HTML a partir do java. Uma das que conheço é [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). Desse modo, você pode fazer o layout do jeito que quiser no android, e quando o usuário interagir com seus botões no layout, por exemplo, você simula clicks nos componentes html (botões, no caso) do site que você quer.

Comment: a idéia é boa, você tem algum exemplo funcional com HTMLUNIT que possa postar aqui?

Comment: Infelizmente não, mas não deve ser difícil de encontrar. O únicos exemplos que tenho são usando jsoup que só extraem a informação do html,  mas não te permite interagir com o site,  é apenas um parser.

Answer (score 0):

Existem alguns sites que utilizam um embed dentro da página, mas existem várias formas de fazer isso. O que normalmente é feito como pode ver neste site --> https://smartseller.com.br é utilizar um CMS por trás consumindo com um API para gerenciar os gets que são feitos e os posts.

O Flask é framework Web pequeno e leve para o Python, que fornece ferramentas e recursos úteis que facilitam a criação de aplicativos Web em Python. Ele dá flexibilidade aos desenvolvedores e é um framework mais acessível para novos desenvolvedores, pois é possível desenvolver um aplicativo Web rapidamente usando apenas um único arquivo Python. O Flask é extensível e não força uma estrutura de diretório em específico. Ele também não exige códigos boilerplate complicados antes de iniciar.

Você usar o Kit de ferramentas de inicialização para estilizar seu aplicativo torná-lo visualmente mais atrativo. A inicialização ajudará você a incorporar páginas Web dinâmicas em seu aplicativo Web e integrar ao seu projeto mobile para que ele funcione bem em navegadores de celulares, sem a necessidade de escrever códigos em HTML, CSS e JavaScript para atingir esses objetivos.

O Flask utiliza o mecanismo de modelo Jinja para desenvolver dinamicamente páginas HTML utilizando conceitos do Python conhecidos, como variáveis, loops, listas e assim por diante. Você utilizar esses exemplos como parte deste seu projeto.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).